# Certificate for FreeRadius

Tags: ssl-certificate, freeradius

I want to purchase commercial SSL certificates for freeRadius server (over linux) to use for PEAP 802.1X Authentication for Windows Clients.
Does anyone know if there is anything in particular that I have to look in the certificate to use it with radius? As far as I have read, a standard SSL certificate should work.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No a standard SSL certificate won't generally work.  It needs to have some very specific OIDs for use with Windows clients.  See `/etc/raddb/certs/xpextensions` for the specific OIDs you need.

Many CAs will include these automatically if you specify you're using the certs for 802.1X.